# Are dll made from Visual Studio 2019 (v142) are imported in Visual Studio 2013 (v120) project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I made a C++ Windows library with Visual Studio 2019 (toolset v142).
Now my library should be included in other C++ project which is build in Visual Studio 2013 (toolset v120).

What I want to know is: Is it a problem to use a dynamic library built with the v142 toolset in a build using the v120 toolset? If so, how can I rebuild the library in Visual Studio 2019 to fix this?

Comment: Does your dll export classes?

Comment: Yes, only class and no top-level functions.

Comment: That tends to be a problem, depending on how clean the DLL interface was designed.  VS2013 uses different runtime libraries, the final process will have multiple copies of the runtime.  Selecting the v120 toolset in the VS2019 project is a simple way to get ahead.  If you don't have VS2013 installed on your dev machine then you want to fix that, given that you'll need it to repro bug reports.

Comment: That's what I'm wondering. When my clients build their project with my library in VS2013 with release mode  there is no problem. But the build failed in debug mode. Is the only way to distribute my library by building it with the v120 toolset? I considered using the v120 toolset in VS2019 to do that, but it seemed impossible. Maybe I'd better install VS2013. Anyway, What is the exact definition of "Clean interface" you said? I would like to find a document containing the concept and study it. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: *But the build failed in debug mode* -- What was the failure?  Also, you may want to consider making the lowest version supported as VS 2015.  Microsoft cleaned up their act with 2015 and beyond.

Comment: ***Is it a problem to use a dynamic library built with the v142 toolset in a build using the v120 toolset?*** Microsoft says that the dll are incompatible: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170) I would not use a dll from toolset v142 in v120.

Comment: ***The Microsoft C++ (MSVC) compiler toolsets in Visual Studio 2013 and earlier don't guarantee binary compatibility across major versions. You can't link object files, static libraries, dynamic libraries, and executables built by different versions of these toolsets. The ABIs, object formats, and runtime libraries are incompatible.***

Comment: The failure message from my client was "there is no ucrtbased.dll ", so I constructed same IDE and platform, and there was no error and works fine. (Windows 10, Visual Studio 2013 C++ project with v120 toolset, imported my library built with v142 toolset, x86 debug mode)   
In this case will it be solved when my client install Windows 10 SDK on his dev machine?

Comment: That's a debug build of the runtime library, you *must* deploy the Release build of your program.

Comment: I know that, I already deployed two libraries built in debug mode and release mode respectively (mylib.dll, mylibd.dll).

Comment: Hi, what specific problem are you currently facing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> When my clients build their project with my library in VS2013 with
> release mode there is no problem. But the build failed in debug mode.

After changing from release to debug mode, the project properties are reset, and you need to manually set it again.

If you use a pure C interface, ensure that the exported things do not have C++ data types and there will be no errors. And you need to make sure your clients use the same environment as you.

If you have to pass the C++ data type, not only the compiler version must be the same, but the C++ version must also be completely consistent. For example, the data structure of MSVC C++17 std::string has changed,
If different versions are passed to each other, the program will crash.